# Math notation question

Tags: probability, notation

When I do my homework,I do not understand this notation in below function.
The function is Let X be a continuous random variable whose probability density
function is:
$$f_X(x) = 3x^21_{[0,1]}(x)$$

What is $1_{[0,1]}(x)$ meaning?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1_S$ means the **characteristic function** or **indicator function** of $S$. That is,
$$ 1_S(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{ if } x \in S \\ 0 &\text{ if } x \not\in S \end{cases}
$$
Therefore, $f$ is the piecewise defined function
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 3x^2 &\text{ if } x \in [0,1] \\ 0 &\text{ if } x \not\in [0,1] \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$1_{[0,1]}(x)$ is by definition the function which is $1$ when $0\le x\le 1$, and $0$ elsewhere.

A perhaps clearer way to define $f_X(x)$ is to say that $f_X(x)=3x^2$ if $0\le x\le 1$, and $f_X(x)=0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's called an "indicator function" and it means that the function only gets its values in the range between 0 and 1, or in other words, its support is between 0 and 1, meaning that it gets truncated otherwise.